# Making millions of transactions reliably

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, plasma

I'll explain the situation :

I want to log Web2 actions onto a blockchain - say, an access log.

On top of that, I'm assuming the content supplied to the browser has passed many hands before reaching the browser, therefore I'd like to send a ping from each member of the chain to "verify" he indeed sent it.

2 key problems arise :

- Exposing Web3 features to Web2 users
- Making millions of transactions

I've heard of [plasma.io](http://plasma.io) and `raiden` for off-chain solution - but I do not know when it will be released or how to even approach this, how do I implement my logic into the off-chain ?

And exposing Web3 features to Web2, I thought about making an HTTP Gateway to Web3 but that would be "centralizing" the data into one server and streaming it into a smart contract - which isn't the most optimal solution.

What are the current ways of achieving such things over Ethereum ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very strong feeling that you will eventually find that putting millions of transactions on Ethereum will be wildly too expensive for whatever you're doing, especially if you think you're going to store the data on the blockchain. It's magnificently expensive. Look at something called IPFS or Swarm.

Comment: My problem resides more in the pinging mechanism, how am I to make millions of pings and verificiations ? I need to implement state channels logic myself I assume